# Using regex pattern and getting CS1003: Syntax error in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

using @ but still error:

[image: error]

Does anyone see why this line:

```
String[] values = Regex.Split(line, @",(?! [\w\d\.\[\]\(\)\#\*\-_])(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

> Error CS1002  ;
>   expected  InsertLogtoDatabase D:\MyProjects\InsertLogWindowsApp\WindowsFormsApplication1\LogOrderi2trade.cs   119
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS1003  Syntax error,
>   ','
>   expected  InsertLogtoDatabase D:\MyProjects\InsertLogWindowsApp\WindowsFormsApplication1\LogOrderi2trade.cs   119

Comment: By the way, please show your code and error message as a plain text, not as an image.

Comment: @Soner Gönül Sorry I'm beginner, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow then. You can read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wanna use `"` with a verbatim string literal, you need to double it like `""`

```
String[] values = Regex.Split(line, @",(?! [\w\d.[]()#*-_])(?=([^\""]\""[^\""]\"")[^\""]$)");
```

From C# spec [$2.4.4.5 String literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> quote-escape-sequence:
>       `""`

Comment: thank you for your help. 
error fixed but I cannot split my value.

Comment: @PapikaWarangwonghirun Sorry but I'm not familiar with regular expressions. And that should be belongs on another question also.